# My VBA module outputs the 'wrong' kind of range. Any ideas?

Tags: vba, excel

Good day to all.  This is my first time asking a question here so please excuse any etiquette mistakes.  I have searched for an answer to my problem but drawn a blank so far, but perhaps I'm asking the wrong question.  My VBA knowledge is self-taught and I'm far from a pro.

I've developed a couple of functions that will compare an input range of text and/or numbers with text token and return a range of true/false answers, so that I can then use that array in array formulas and so on.  The reason is to develop a way of dealing with a problem I have later, this is just a dev project until I can get it working.

My code is:

```
Option Explicit

Function EvalStr(Inp As String) As Integer
'
Dim result As Boolean
'
Application.Volatile
result = Evaluate(Inp)
If result Then
    EvalStr = 1
Else
    EvalStr = 0
End If
End Function

Function EvalRng(TestStr As String, InpRng As Range, Optional ForceHigh As Boolean) As Double()
'
Dim OutRng()    As Double
Dim RngSize     As Long
Dim ThisStr     As String
Dim i           As Integer
'    
RngSize = InpRng.Cells.Count
ReDim OutRng(RngSize - 1) As Double
'
If RngSize > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To RngSize
        ThisStr = "=" & InpRng(i).Value2 & TestStr
        OutRng(i - 1) = EvalStr(ThisStr)
    Next i
End If
EvalRng = OutRng
End Function
```

My spreadsheet is attached as an image so you can see what is going on.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQNyW.png)

```
A2 is just >=6 entered as text.
C2:C11 is a series of incremental numbers, the source data.
D2:D11 are some manually entered zeroes and ones, a baseline for the logic of A2.
F2:F11 is =EvalStr(C2&$A$2)
G2 is =SUMPRODUCT(EvalRng($A$2,C2:C11),C2:C11)
D15:F15 is =SUMPRODUCT($C2:$C11,D2:D11)
Ignore column E
```

D15 is the control sample.  F15 also works, so my Functions are half right.  G2 does not, and I'm stumped as to why, I've reached the limit of my knowledge.

When I use the Formula Entry dialog to work out why it's not working, my array result from EvalRng is separated with commas, whereas the other range is separated with semi-colons.  So I'm guessing my EvalRng is the 'wrong' kind of array...?  How do I fix that?

[The dialog box clue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxkvg.png)

Many thanks for any tips or assistance.

Matt

Comment: Shot in the dark based on commas vs semicolons: try transposing the output (i.e. it could be a row vs column issue?)

Comment: I think you need to return 2D array for vertical range, or `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(EvalRng($A$2,C2:C11)),C2:C11)`

Comment: @Slai Your comment just missed one thing - changing the code to return a 2D array fixes it, and the formula also fixes it *providing it is entered as an array formula*.

Comment: Both you and Patrick are correct, of course!  Thanks for the solution.  I'll go with the one that fixes the problem in the code but your TRANSPOSE trick is a good tool to have in the box.

Thank you.

Comment: there are probably few ways to avoid VBA as some functions like COUNTIF accept string conditions like `C2 & ">=6"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your output a two-dimensional array it will work:

```
Function EvalRng(TestStr As String, InpRng As Range, Optional ForceHigh As Boolean) As Double()
    '
    Dim OutRng()    As Double
    Dim RngSize     As Long
    Dim ThisStr     As String
    Dim i           As Integer
    '
    RngSize = InpRng.Cells.Count
    ReDim OutRng(RngSize - 1, 0) As Double
    '
    If RngSize > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To RngSize
            ThisStr = "=" & InpRng(i).Value2 & TestStr
            OutRng(i - 1, 0) = EvalStr(ThisStr)
        Next i
    End If
    EvalRng = OutRng
End Function
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the formula suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236273/my-vba-module-outputs-the-wrong-kind-of-range-any-ideas/48236362#comment83455348_48236273) by [Slai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383168/slai), but you will need to enter that as an array formula (i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering the formula):

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(EvalRng($A$2,C2:C11)),C2:C11)}
```

Comment: Works flawlessly!  I can't thank you enough for this.  I've been trying to work it out for two hours.

Appreciate this immensely, thanks again.